# How I can calculate the broadcast IP from an IP address and netmask in Perl?

Tags: perl

Does someone have example in Perl of how I can calculate the broadcast IP from an IP address and netmask?

Comment: Downvoter: Please provide a reason. New users will never learn if you don't tell them what they're doing wrong. Simply downvoting a 1 rep user does nothing except discourage new users from using SO.

Comment: It wasn't me, but this is a question that is very easy to get answers to by going to http://search.cpan.org and entering a search term like "IP address" or "netmask".

Comment: I agree with you thx for the help , I am realy new user and just ask about example , again thx

Comment: @shulus: no worries. before you've done something the first time, it's much harder, and it's difficult for those of us who find it easy to remember that it wasn't always that way! :)

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? How to do it, or how to do it in Perl? What have you tried so far?

Comment: hi brian , I am not perl expert I actually write shell script , sometimes I need help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done with the CPAN modules [Net::IP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::IP) and [Net::Netmask](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::Netmask):

```
my $ip = Net::IP->new('192.168.1.1');
my $block = Net::Netmask->new('192.168.1.1');

print "netmask: ", $ip->mask(), "\n";
print "broadcast: ", $block->broadcast(), "\n";
```

Comment: Ether this is very simple example , sorry about my question

Answer (score 8):

Why not use modules from CPAN. For example [`NetAddr::IP`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?NetAddr::IP):

```
 my $ip = NetAddr::IP->new('124.2.4.6', '255.255.255.0');
 print $ip->broadcast();
```

Comment: NetAddr::IP has been my goto for anything IP related for a while now; it handles everything.